# Como criar dicionário a partir de listas

Tags: python, lista, csv, dicionário

Como associar listas às chaves e valores para criar um dicionário no Python?

O problema é o seguinte? tenho um grande arquivo csv e preciso ler a primeira linha (transformo numa lista) que deverá ser usada para associar às Chaves e as linhas seguintes deverão ser os valores.

Um opção que imaginei seria usar loops for para ler cada item das listas e fazer a atribuição. Mas não tem uma função / método que faça isso?

Segue um trecho do código, considerando apenas o cabeçalho (keys) e a primeira linha (valores).

O próximo passo será montar uma lista de dicionários, cada um para cada linha; mas isso creio que sei como fazer.

```html
f = open("beatles-diskography.csv", "r")

hd = f.readline()
fl = f.readline()
hd = hd.split(',')
fl = fl.split(',')

c = 0
for s in hd:
    s = s.strip()
    hd[c] = s
    c = c+1

c = 0
for s in fl:
    s = s.strip()
    fl[c] = s
    c = c+1

'''
dic = ???
'''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é você utilizar a classe [*DictReader*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) do módulo [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html), que mapeia a informação para um tipo [*OrderedDict*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (dicionário que mantém a ordem de entrada).

Exemplo:

```
import csv

# Abre o arquivo
with open("beatles-diskography.csv", "r") as f:
    # Lê os dados do csv no formato OrderedDict
    rd = csv.DictReader(f)
    for linha in rd:
        # Exemplo de acesso aos dados
        print("{0} - {1} - {2}".format(linha['Title'], linha['Released'], linha['Label']))
```

Saída do exemplo:

```
Please Please Me - 22 March 1963 - Parlophone(UK)
With the Beatles - 22 November 1963 - Parlophone(UK)
Beatlemania! With the Beatles - 25 November 1963 - Capitol(CAN)
Introducing... The Beatles - 10 January 1964 - Vee-Jay(US)
Meet the Beatles! - 20 January 1964 - Capitol(US)
Twist and Shout - 3 February 1964 - Capitol(CAN)
The Beatles' Second Album - 10 April 1964 - Capitol(US)
The Beatles' Long Tall Sally - 11 May 1964 - Capitol(CAN)
...
```

Comment: Código elegante! +1